# Ruby: Can I update the system environment variables?

Tags: ruby

Is there a way to update a system's PATH variable through Ruby, permanently? I have the following:

```
envPath = ENV["PATH"].dup
if envPath.include? "C:\\oracle\\product\\11.2.0\\client_1\\bin;" then
    envPath.slice! "C:\\oracle\\product\\11.2.0\\client_1\\bin;"
    ENV["PATH"] = envPath
    puts ENV["PATH"]
end
```

This successfully removes the variable I want to, but only for the current window - not permanently.

Comment: Looks like I can do it by calling [SETX](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3835518/can-a-script-bat-make-changes-to-windows-path-environment-variable)

Comment: Cool. I wasn't aware of `SETX`. :)

Answer (score 1):

It's more a question about general computing and process behaviour not ruby special.

**No this is not possible during runtime**. Only a father process can configure the environment of it's child **before** start. Changing the environment of the father process or other processes during runtime isn't supported by any OS.