# Adding the current directory to Windows path permanently

Tags: batch-file, command-line, path, environment-variables

I am trying to add the current directory (from a command-line) to Windows path permanently, but I am having serious problems implementing this.

My initial attempt was:

```
set PATH=%PATH%;%cd%
```

However, this only works in the current session; as soon as I close the command-line window, the `PATH` environment variable retains its previous value.

Next, I tried:

```
setx PATH=%PATH%;%cd%
```

This might work in Windows 7 and 8 according to some of the answers that I found here, but in Windows 10, the `setx` command has three ways of working:

```
Syntax 1:
    SETX [/S system [/U [domain\]user [/P [password]]]] var value [/M]

Syntax 2:
    SETX [/S system [/U [domain\]user [/P [password]]]] var /K regpath [/M]

Syntax 3:
    SETX [/S system [/U [domain\]user [/P [password]]]]
         /F file {var {/A x,y | /R x,y string}[/M] | /X} [/D delimiters]
```

Long story short, I am unable to get it to work:

```
ERROR: Invalid syntax. Default option is not allowed more than '2' time(s).
```

How can I complete my goal the easiest way?

If there's a different syntax per Windows version, then I'd be happy to get this info as well.

Comment: I'd try omitting the `=`

Comment: @Magoo: Funny, I just did that; No luck though...

Comment: @Magoo: I get `ERROR: Invalid syntax. Default option is not allowed more than '2' time(s).`.

Comment: @Magoo: OK, double-quotes around the second argument have solved this: `setx PATH "%PATH%;%cd%"`. Thank you!!!!!!

Comment: @Magoo: More precisely: `setx PATH "%cd%"`. The syntax that I have mentioned above "replicates" the entire `PATH` (and mostly truncates the result to 1024 characters), which makes it a pretty bad idea.

Comment: Ah, yes - if your `path` or `cd` contains spaces. Personally, I'd google for `path editor` - good freebies available.

Answer (score 5):

It is not good to modify **system** or **user** `PATH` from within a batch file by simply overwriting or appending a folder path to `PATH` stored in registry using the **local** `PATH` as described in detail in the answer on [Why are other folder paths also added to system PATH with SetX and not only the specified folder path?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25919222/3074564)

One solution for this task to add current directory path to **user** `PATH` is using this code:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
for /F "skip=2 tokens=1,2*" %%G in ('%SystemRoot%\System32\reg.exe query "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Environment" /v "Path" 2^>nul') do (
    if /I "%%G" == "Path" (
        set "UserPath=%%I"
        if defined UserPath goto CheckPath
    )
)

set "UseSetx=1"
if not "%CD:~1024,1%" == "" set "UseSetx="
if not exist %SystemRoot%\System32\setx.exe set "UseSetx="
if defined UseSetx (
    %SystemRoot%\System32\setx.exe Path "%CD%" >nul
) else (
    %SystemRoot%\System32\reg.exe ADD "HKCU\Environment" /f /v Path /t REG_SZ /d "%CD%" >nul
)

endlocal
exit /B

:CheckPath
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
if "!UserPath:~-1!" == ";" (set "Separator=") else "Separator=;"
set "PathCheck=!UserPath!%Separator%"
if not "!PathCheck:%CD%;=!" == "!PathCheck!" goto EndBatch
if not "!PathCheck:%CD%\;=!" == "!PathCheck!" goto EndBatch
set "PathToSet=!UserPath!%Separator%%CD%"
set "UseSetx=1"
if not "!PathToSet:~1024,1!" == "" set "UseSetx="
if not exist %SystemRoot%\System32\setx.exe set "UseSetx="
if defined UseSetx (
    %SystemRoot%\System32\setx.exe Path "!PathToSet!" >nul
) else (
    set "ValueType=REG_EXPAND_SZ"
    if "!PathToSet:%%=!" == "!PathToSet!" set "ValueType=REG_SZ"
    %SystemRoot%\System32\reg.exe ADD "HKCU\Environment" /f /v Path /t !ValueType! /d "!PathToSet!" >nul
)
:EndBatch
endlocal
endlocal
```

The disadvantage of this solution is a **user** `PATH` being finally for example `C:\Temp;C:\Temp\Other Folder;C:\Temp\One More Folder` when current directory is first `C:\Temp`, on next run of the batch file `C:\Temp\Other Folder` and `C:\Temp\One More Folder` on third execution of the batch file.

The solution to avoid this is a definition of an application specific environment variable called in next batch file `MyAppPath` which is always overwritten on execution of the batch file. There is added to the **user** `PATH` only the reference to the environment variable `MyAppPath` if not already existing in **user** `PATH`.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
set "UseSetx=1"
if not "%CD:~1024,1%" == "" set "UseSetx="
if not exist %SystemRoot%\System32\setx.exe set "UseSetx="
if defined UseSetx (
    %SystemRoot%\System32\setx.exe MyAppPath "%CD%" >nul
) else (
    %SystemRoot%\System32\reg.exe ADD "HKCU\Environment" /f /v MyAppPath /t REG_SZ /d "%CD%" >nul
)

set "UserPath="
for /F "skip=2 tokens=1,2*" %%G in ('%SystemRoot%\System32\reg.exe query "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Environment" /v "Path" 2^>nul') do (
    if /I "%%G" == "Path" (
        set "UserPath=%%I"
        if defined UserPath goto CheckPath
    )
)

if exist %SystemRoot%\System32\setx.exe (
    %SystemRoot%\System32\setx.exe Path "%%MyAppPath%%" >nul
) else (
    %SystemRoot%\System32\reg.exe ADD "HKCU\Environment" /f /v Path /t REG_EXPAND_SZ /d "%%MyAppPath%%" >nul
)
endlocal
exit /B

:CheckPath
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
if "!UserPath:~-1!" == ";" (set "Separator=") else set "Separator=;"
if "!UserPath:%%MyAppPath%%=!" == "!UserPath!" (
    set "PathToSet=!UserPath!%Separator%%%MyAppPath%%"
    set "UseSetx=1"
    if not "!PathToSet:~1024,1!" == "" set "UseSetx="
    if not exist %SystemRoot%\System32\setx.exe set "UseSetx="
    if defined UseSetx (
        %SystemRoot%\System32\setx.exe Path "!PathToSet!" >nul
    ) else (
        %SystemRoot%\System32\reg.exe ADD "HKCU\Environment" /f /v Path /t REG_EXPAND_SZ /d "!PathToSet!" >nul
    )
)
endlocal
endlocal
```

In this case **user** `PATH` as stored in registry contains always just `%MyAppPath%` and registry value is of type **REG_EXPAND_SZ**. The value of environment variable `MyAppPath` is also stored in registry, but is of type **REG_SZ**. The value of `MyAppPath` is updated to current directory path on each execution of the batch file. So the **user** `PATH` in registry does not get longer and longer on each execution of a batch file from a different folder than before.

In general an application or application suite is not good coded if its application folder or one of its subfolders must be in **local** `PATH` on execution of the application or any application from the suite to work properly at all. The application or application suite can store its installation path also somewhere else in registry like `App Paths` or in a file in a subfolder of `%APPDATA%` (user account related standard application data path) from which it can be read on next run. An installer package should modify **user** or **system** `PATH` only if this application is most likely executed mainly from within a command prompt window by a user.

To understand the commands used and how they work, open a [command prompt](https://www.howtogeek.com/235101/) window, execute there the following commands, and read the displayed help pages for each command, entirely and carefully.

- `echo /?`
- `endlocal /?`
- `exit /?`
- `for /?`
- `goto /?`
- `if /?`
- `reg /?`
- `reg add /?`
- `reg query /?`
- `set /?`
- `setlocal /?`
- `setx /?`

Following should be also read:

- Wikipedia article about [Windows Environment Variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environment_variable#Windows).
- Microsoft article about [Using command redirection operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-xp/bb490982(v=technet.10)) explaining `>nul`.
- Answer on [Where is "START" searching for executables?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27386403/3074564) with details about `App Paths`.
- Answer on [What is the reason for "X is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file"?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41461002/3074564) with details about **local**, **system** and **user** `PATH`.
- Answer on [How to set PATH environment variable in batch file only once on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31885906/)
- Answer on [How can I use a .bat file to remove specific tokens from the PATH environment variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38664286/3074564)

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution:

The syntax of `setx` is slightly different than the syntax of `set`.

With `set`, I would do:

```
set PATH=%PATH%;%cd%
```

With `setx`, I needed to do:

```
setx PATH "%cd"
```

The first argument specifies the name of the environment variable.

The second argument specifies the value to add to this variable.

The double-quotes are required for when the second argument contains spaces.

This might also be the case with `set`, by the way.

Comment: @goodvibration, that's overwriting the user's current value of `PATH`. If you want easy access to this for the per-user `PATH`, then add a `MYPATH` variable that's expanded (i.e. no percent variables). Then in the user `PATH` you can include `%MYPATH%`. This `MYPATH` value will be stored as a `REG_SZ` value because it has no variables. This is important because it means it gets loaded in the first pass before loading `REG_EXPAND_SZ` values such as `PATH`. The two-pass load allows `REG_EXPAND_SZ` values to reliably depend on `REG_SZ` values.

Comment: @eryksun: Can you please provide a written answer step by step? I find it hard to conclude what exactly I should do? Ideally, I would like to execute one or more command lines. Thank you!

Comment: My suggestion is only intended to make it simpler to extend the user `PATH` in the future. For example, assuming `MYPATH` exists, you could run `setx MYPATH "%MYPATH%;%CD%"`. You still need to modify the user's `PATH` value in `HKCU\Environment` to include the unexpanded `%MYPATH%` variable. For that you can use the GUI environment variable editor, or adapt Mofi's code that combines reg.exe and setx.exe.

Comment: @eryksun : so there is no way to completely automate adding the current working dir to the PATH that keeps all parts of the system up-to-date (Registry, etc)?

Comment: @shellter, as Mofi's code shows, the way to do this for the current user in a script is to use reg.exe to read "PATH" from "HKCU\Environment", append to it, and write it back with setx.exe. Writing the value with setx.exe broadcasts a `WM_SETTINGCHANGE` message to make Explorer reload its environment from the registry, so processes subsequently run from Explorer will have the updated environment.

Comment: @eryksun : Thanks for pointing out Mofi's answer. It hadn't been posted when I added my comment. And thanks for your further explanation, it makes complete sense to me now! Good luck to all.

Comment: I know this answer is 5 years old, but please delete this. This is a permanent destruction of the path variable. Someone will use this and cause harm to their system.